# How does one use an IEnumerable<string> as replacement of a TextReader?

Tags: c#, sql, xml, deserialization

I am working on a TimeRegistry. I have a C# program running that reads and XML file, downloads new data from a server, adds it to the XML file and exports the data from the XML file to an SQL database. What I would like to do is skip the part in which the XML file is used as input. I would like the select data from the SQL database, use this to get data from the server and then add it to the SQL database.

The problem is however, that the SDK that I am using only accepts a certain type as input. I have added the classes that contain this type. To better understand my question, I have also added a working code sample and the new non-working code sample. Could someone please help me to convert my list of strings to a stream that can be deserialized to the Events type? (Or has a better idea to solving this problem)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f856/8

## original sample that works

```
    public static Events Load(string aFileName)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Events));
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(aFileName);
        try
        {
            return (Events)xs.Deserialize(tr);
        }
        finally
        {
            tr.Close();
            tr.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

## new sample that does not work

```
    public static Events Load()
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Events));
        using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("TimeReg")))            
        {
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<string> lst = connection.Query<string>($"select * from Events");
                var stream = new ByteStream(Encode(lst, Encoding.UTF8));
                return (Events)xs.Deserialize(stream);      
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
         }
     }
```

## Classes that contain the required datatype

```
    public static Events Load(string aFileName)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Events));
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(aFileName);
        try
        {
            return (Events)xs.Deserialize(tr);
        }
        finally
        {
            tr.Close();
            tr.Dispose();
        }
    }


    public Events()
    {
        EventList = new List<ReadEventRequestResponse.DATA>();
    }

    static public class ReadEventRequestResponse
    {
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DATA")]
        public class DATA
        {
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "dt")]
            public string LocalTime { get; set; }
```

## Input to WriteXML

```
    public class Events
{        
    public List<ReadEventRequestResponse.DATA> EventList { get; set; }

    public Events()
    {
        EventList = new List<ReadEventRequestResponse.DATA>();
    }
    const string FILENAME = @"C:\Users\...\Documents\Events_check.xml";
    public static Events Load(string aFileName)
    {
        
        DataTable dt = null;
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Events));
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connection string")
        {
            try
            {
                string query = "select * from Events";
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
                dt = new DataTable("Events");
                adapter.Fill(dt);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
            dt.WriteXml(FILENAME);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            dt.WriteXml(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            try
            {
                return (Events)xs.Deserialize(ms);
            }
            finally
            {
                ms.Close();
                ms.Dispose();
            }

        }
    }
```

## Output from WriteXML using DataTable

[image]

## Output from WriteXML using DataSet

[image]

## Desired Output XML

[image]

Comment: XML is a text file.  Start by looking at the file aFileName with notepad.  For code to work you need to convert the query response into XML format.  I will work on sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication23
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = null;
            DataRow row = null;
            MemoryStream ms = null;
            //add test data to datatable
            //this is equivalent to the adapter.Fill below.
            //remove this code when getting data from query
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("sernum", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("id",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("dt", typeof(DateTime));
            row = dt.Rows.Add();
            row["dt"] = DateTime.Parse("2022-03-30T19:10:33+02:00");
            row = dt.Rows.Add();
            row["dt"] = DateTime.Parse("2022-03-30T19:10:33+02:00");

            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Events xmlns:xsi=\"w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instaqnce\" xmlns:xsd=\"w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"></Events>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);
            XElement events = doc.Root;
            XElement eventList = new XElement("EventList");
            events.Add(eventList);


            //move this code to after the try below where query files the datatable
            foreach(DataRow dataRow in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                XElement data = new XElement("DATA", new XAttribute("dt", dataRow.Field<DateTime>("dt").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")));
                eventList.Add(data);
            }
            doc.Save(FILENAME);
            ms = new MemoryStream();
            doc.Save(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;

            Console.ReadLine();


            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string");
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
            {
                try
                {
                    string query = "select * from Events";
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
                    dt = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }


                doc.Save(FILENAME);
                ms = new MemoryStream();
                doc.Save(ms);
                ms.Position = 0;                    
                try
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    ms.Close();
                    ms.Dispose();
                }

            }

        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: It seems to work using a memorystream. However, I cannot verify. As  you suggested, I am converting to XML format, but get a "There is an error in XML document (1, 2)."
the format I need is 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Events xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <EventList>
    <DATA dt="2022-06-20 14:34" />
 <DATA dt="2022-06-20 14:34" />
  </EventList>
</Events>

I tried "select * from Events For XML PATH('EventList'), ROOT('Events')" and I tried "select * from Events For XML RAW('DATA'), ROOT('Events')"

Comment: Thus, the only problem that remains is combining RAW and PATH in one SQL query.

Comment: I need to see the difference between what [dt.WriteXml(FILENAME);] produces and the expected results.

Comment: I added two images; the first is a censored version of [dt.WriteXml(FILENAME);] and the second is a edited version of the desired format. As you can see, I only mentioned datetime dt, but there are many more fields. I did not remove these from the censored version, as these appear to be randomly placed on new rows. I would at least expect every row to start with "sernum"

Comment: I'm confused.  The XML you posted doesn't look like it is generated from my code.  My code should generate Events as root tag and only one instance.  What you posted has DocumentElement as root and multiple Event Tags.  It looks like data is save in database as XML.

Comment: ah yes, you are right. I already added Raw and Root to the select statement. Ill add a new one.

Comment: You just added a larger version of what you already had.  Not what is coming from Writexml file in my code.

Comment: It was a bit different as it contained al items on 1 row. I'll leave that for now, because otherwise we are drifting away from the problem. I have instead added my "interpretation" of your code, that outputs the XML as posted. Exact formatting aside, I find it strange that the file can be read from SQL, successfully transformed and written as XML in the type of Events, but that it gives "There is an error in XML document (1, 2)"  error.

Comment: I don't se your comments.  My code has dt = new DataTable("Events"); where Events should appear as root tag in table and only occurs once.

Comment: I have added the code to the main question; just above the "output from xml" block

Comment: You should only create the DataTable once an not put into an Event.  This way you get data appended instead of just last occurrence.  I can easily convert the dt table to correct XML format.  I just want to know where DocumentElement tag is coming from.  It needs to be removed.  I think we may need a new DataSet("Events").  Than add DataTable("Event") into the ds.

Comment: I have changed DataTable dt to DataSet ds and posted the result above. It does the same, but now DocumentElement is replaced by Events and Events is geplaced by Table.

Comment: I updated my code to use xml linq instead of xml serialize..  The code has to be moved around.  I just created code in a way that was easy to test without using a database.  So I manually create two  rows of the datatable instead of getting rows from query.

Comment: The format of the xml file was perfect, however, to return the xml file in the type of "Event" I had to deserialize it, but XmlSerializer does not take Xdocument as input. I added doc.Save(ms) after doc.save(FILENAME). Thanks you very much!

Comment: You could use doc.ToString() which would return a string instead of a Event.  ToString() is much quicker than serialize.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server can generate xml for You, since that is what you're trying to parse the strings as by the looks of it, try this

```
IEnumerable<string> lst = connection.Query<string>("select * from Events FOR XML PATH");
```

Presuming that your connection query does return a valid string result if all row is now in a XML string. If not let me know I will verify that part semantics as well :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but the result of "select * from Events FOR XML PATH" looks completely different when run in SQL server management studio vs running from a console app and writing to XML.